# Should JPA Repositories be created by Table or Object?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

What is the best practice for creating JPA Repositories?

Right now I have two tables: **Media** and **Ratings**.

To find media that is similar a query has to be made to the **Rating** table to find the interconnections between the different media. This query then returns a list of **Media** objects.

Should this query be placed in the **Rating** repository (as it queries the **Rating** table),
or in the **Media** repository (as it returns a collection of **Media** objects with the IDs set)?

I have tried searching for best-practices for this particular use-case but haven't found anything relevant.

Update:
The SQL query is defined like this:

```
@Query(value=[SQL query with several joins],nativeQuery=true)
List<Media> mySQLQuery()
```

it returns a list of `mediaId`'s which can be returned from the function as `Media` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a custom implementation of the repository, implementing a custom interface.

First I had to declare the interface:

```
public interface CustomQuery {
    public List<Integer>myCustomQuery(int id)
}
```

Then I implemented it in my custom repository. The name is important, it has to begin with the name of the repository interface it is extending. My repo is named `MediaRepository` so I named the custom implementation `MediaRepositoryImpl`:

```
@Component
public class MediaRepositoryImpl implements CustomQuery {
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager manager;

    public List<Integer>myCustomQuery(int id){
        Query q = manager.createNativeQuery(SQL_QUERY_GOES_HERE);
        List<Integer> ids = new ArratList<Integer>();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Integer> result  = q.getResultList();
        for(Integer o : result){
            //process the results and add them to the list
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

This way, you can do custom native queries while still keeping the regular Repositories clean. This approach is also easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably neither.

You see when you implement a Repository and do for example findAll() you will get a List of all Objects from the Entity used in the Repository creation.

```
  interface MyRepo implements<Media, Long>....

  myRepo.findAll() will return a List of Media objects.
```

What you are trying to do is out of scope from a Repository as it acts on only that particular Entity with a finit operations *on that particular Entity*.

Also it seems to me that **Media** and **Ratings** are connected with a OneToMany or ManyToMany, then this definitely should go to a separate DAO method.

Comment: @mmoraga I just answered, no. This should be a separate DAO method.

Comment: So queries that are not finit operations on a particular entity should not be put in the Repo? Where should these queries go instead then? Loading all ratings is not an option :)

Comment: @mmoraga you need a DAO method for that. NamedQuery or QueryDSL, etc if you are using spring.

Comment: I updated my question now to show which method is used for the query itself. If I understand you correctly, you're saying this method should go in another class?